# Is there a way to access whether a portion of a webpage is being rendered on screen or not via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, gpu

Currently our logic runs within an iframe on clients pages. We have the request to now detect whether that iFrame is currently in the viewing window or not (scrolled off-screen).

I just had an idea that this might be something that the GPU might already have which would allow for it to provide better performance on the page with regards to what it is rendering and I wanted to know if anyone was aware of whether this data was accessible via an API/lib such as OpenGL.

I am aware that providing actual pixel info, could be a large security issue, however just having access to whether or not a specific iFrame was being rendered would be helpful for viewability detection.

Is anyone aware of whether there is a way to do this? Current reading so far is not showing this as being possible, but I am continuing my search and thought I would post here as well.

Any info or direction would be helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate if the object is inside your viewport or not.

http://plnkr.co/edit/91gybbZ7sYVELEYvy1IK?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  myElement = $('.someObject');
  window.onscroll = function() {

    var screenTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var screenBottom = screenTop + $(window).height();    
    var elTop = $(myElement).offset().top;
    var elBottom = elTop + $(myElement).height();

    var info = 'screenTop:' + screenTop + ' screenBottom:' + screenBottom + ' elTop:' + elTop + ' elBottom:' + elBottom;

    if((elBottom <= screenBottom) && (elTop >= screenTop)) {
      $('.info').html('Element is in view + <small>' + info + '</small>');
    } else {
      $('.info').html('Element is out of view + <small>' + info + '</small>');
    }

  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Gerfried. Unfortunately it seems that when working from within an iFrame from another domain, one does not have access to the parent window element as you get null returned.

Comment: that's true - if the iframe is from another origin (domain) there is no way to access its content.