# Vimeo iFrame Play & Pause out of Viewport

Tags: jquery, html, video, vimeo

I'm trying to get my embedded Vimeo video to pause on exiting the viewport and allow another embedded Vimeo video to play upon entering viewport.

I've been exploring various solutions and discovered Froogaloop which works perfectly, however I believe is the old Vimeo api.

I got an exact example working of the video pausing on exiting, but its using an ID rather than class so unable to use on more than one video and not entirely sure how to accomplish this.

[Example - Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Djsquid/2Lq5jesf/2/)

```
<div class="inner">
<iframe id="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/220643186? 
autoplay=1&loop=1&color=357ded&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="640" 
height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
 var iframe = document.getElementById('video');

// $f == Froogaloop
var player = $f(iframe);

var inner = $(".inner");
var elementPosTop = inner.position().top;
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var elementFromTop = elementPosTop - scrollPos;

    if (elementFromTop > 0 && elementFromTop < elementPosTop + viewportHeight) {
        inner.addClass("active");
        player.api("play");
    } else {
        inner.removeClass("active");
        player.api("pause");
    }
});
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need different player objects - one for each iframe. For performance reasons you should create the list of players outside of your onScroll function.

```
var players = []
$('.inner').each(function() {
  players.push({
      player: new Vimeo.Player($(this).find("iframe").get(0)),
      top: $(this).position().top,
      status: "paused"
  })
});
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    for(var i=0; i<players.length;i++) {
        var elementFromTop = players[i].top - scrollPos;
      var status = (elementFromTop > 0 && elementFromTop < players[i].top + viewportHeight) ? "play" : "pause";   
      if(players[i].status != status) {
          players[i].status = status;
          players[i].player[status]();
          console.log(i, status);      
      }
    }
});
```

You can test here: https://jsfiddle.net/oxf4dtn3/

Note: it is not possible to start any video automatically, if its sound is on. You can mute vimeo videos using the parameter "&muted=1"

Comment: Hey Gerfried, thank you so much for your help! this is brilliant, I tried your code and I have it partially working. My videos actually don't have any sound, and they are all set to autoplay, What I have noticed is the very top video doesn't play after scroll, and I believe the videos below continue to play despite out of viewport. I put together a real mockup of what I'm actually doing. The first jsfiddle was to test a video with sound to ensure it was pausing. This is my latest test - https://jsfiddle.net/Djsquid/43c9w27s/2/

Comment: You can finetune your condition for the status a bit... https://jsfiddle.net/Lp4wg320/

Comment: Apologises I am a novice with Jquery, I see what you've added which allows me to control / tweak the height from the top of the viewport, does this allow me to control how much of the video below is shown before playing also? For some reason only videos at the top of the viewport are pausing and not the ones at the bottom.

Comment: Just play around with the +300 / -300 values. You can also improve your function by taking the height of the video into the calculation. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299291

Comment: Can you help me with my problem also?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API):

```
require(['https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js'], function(Vimeo) {
    var vimeoVideos = document.querySelectorAll('.inner iframe');
    vimeoVideos.forEach(function(iframe){
        var player = new Vimeo(iframe);
        player.ready().then(function() {
            var observer = new IntersectionObserver(
                (entries) => {
                    entries.forEach((entry) => {
                        player.getPaused().then(function(paused){
                            if (!entry.isIntersecting && !paused) {
                                player.pause();
                            } else if (entry.isIntersecting && paused) {
                                player.play();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
                { threshold: 0.2 }
            );
            observer.observe(player.element);
        });
    });
});
```